# --exec APP command not working in scrot

Tags: scrot-command

I am trying to run --exec command in Scrot to open an image in an APP from command line. But it is not opening the desired image, instead it is listing the contents of the directory or displaying all the images of the directory.

```
scrot --exec APP filename
```

here, APP means any image editor

```
scrot --exec gthumb abc.jpg
```

I am running this command but it's not working

Comment: Please post the entire command. Do so by editing your post.

Comment: Try `scrot -e 'gthumb abc.jpg'`

Comment: My suggestion is based on `scrot '%Y-%m-%d_$wx$h.png' -e 'mv $f ~/shots/'` from scrot's man page.

Comment: DK Bose I am satisfied with your answer :)